# Get list of javascript functions in file

Tags: autocompletion, functions

The functionality that I am after, is to get a list of the javascript functions present in the file that I am in. Clicking a function in the list will then take me to that function.

How do I go about getting this functionality?

Comment: You will need  to play with tags ([`:h tags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tags)) usually they are generated with something like [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) but it seems that for JS, [doctor js](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs) works better.

Answer (score 1):

You need [TagBar](https://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar/) and for JavaScript any of the [external dependencies suggested in the wiki](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/wiki#javascript)